# install ctan package ragged2e for latex on nixos

Tags: installation, latex, nix, nixos, tex-live

**tldr:** I need to know how to install the **ragged2e** package on nixos.

I have a latex project that uses the package **ragged2e** ([here it is on ctan](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e)). More concrete, it contains the line `\usepackage{ragged2e}`. I want to build this project on my nixos machine.

I am very new to nix and nixos. I did read the [texlive section](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-language-texlive) of the nixos manual (although I didn't understand the last part about "custom packages").
My nixos config contains the following line:

```hs
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
  # ... some other packages
  texlive.combine {
    inherit (texlive) scheme-basic latexmk etoolbox babel-german;
  }
];
```

Unfortunatelly the package ragged2e doesn't seem to be available on nixos: The following doesn't provide any results:

```sh
$ nix repl
nix-repl> :l <nixpkgs>
nix-repl> texlive.ragged<TAB>
```

So now I don't know how to install the ragged2e package.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with nixos. Normally I would recommend to install vanilla texlive directly from the tug site: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html This will not only give a more up-to-date version then the ones packaged for linux, but you can also use `tlmgr` to easily install individual packages including their dependencies.